# Getting javascript to re-run after (failed) HttpPost call to controller in MVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have an apparently trivial but annoying problem when using MVC that occurs when posting to a Controller endpoint. It would seem that the call to View(model) (called if the model is not valid - see code below) does not reload the HTML page. However, I have a form that takes some time to process, so I have set up a modal loading screen that sets its display tag to 'block' when the user submits the form. However, if there is an error in the form, the form is returned with the list of errors provided by the @Html.ValidationSummary helper. When this happens, my modal screen is still active, so the user cannot modify their form data.

Typically one has something like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(SomeModel model)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return View(model);
   }

   // ... code on success
}
```

What I originally tried was to put some JavaScript on the page that set the display attribute of my modal div back to 'none'. However, it soon became apparent that this code is not run when the endpoint returns - only on the original HttpGet call. This also begs the question of how the elements of the @Html.ValidationSummary are being set. Is this being set server-side?

The problem I am left with is I do not seem to have a way of accomplishing the very simple task of setting an HTML attribute. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!